# Ant copy cannot interpret %2527

Tags: ant, salesforce, urlencode

**I'm in the following situation:** I'm using `ant` to migrate certain `salesforce files` to other *salesforce environments*. Business users are also **developing** on *Salesforce* and that's why sometimes they use special characters in names. I have a certain file named `Contracts_Product__c-Contract%27s Option Layout.layout (Mind the %27 in it)`. This is how *Salesforce* delivers this file to me, so I don't have any influence on that.

Now somewhere in my script, I need to copy this file to another location so I use the following command:

`<copy file="${svn.sources}/${object-test}" tofile="${release.sources}/${object-test}"/>`

The content of object-test property is `/home/../layouts/Contracts_Product__c-Contract%2527s%20Option%20Layout.layout`, which normally is exactly the file name that I need `(%2527 decodes to %27)` but ant complains he cannot find the file.

Any tips on how I can work around this issue, without changing my source filename ?

Comment: Please see if the [link](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/502495/url-encoding-and-decoding-question/) of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. By adding some javascript to URL-decode the path before passing it to the ant-copy command, ant accepts it and succesfully copies the file, including the %27 in the output filename.

Code needed:

```
<script language="javascript">
    <![CDATA[
        var urltodecode = project.getProperty("object");                                                    
        var decodedurl = decodeURIComponent(urltodecode);

        // Set a new property which could be retrieved by the ant script
        project.setProperty("objectDecoded", decodedurl);
    ]]>
</script>
```